# PHP bug for 2 character strings?

Tags: php, substring, substr

Given the string `$s` and the function `substr(substr($s, 1), -1)` you would expect one character to be taken off the front and one off the back.

Which is what you get if you run `substr(substr('abc', 1), -1) === 'b'` And, if you run it on `ab` you get `b`.

However, If you run `substr(substr($s, -1), 1)` you get the desired result on 2 character strings.

This is the same in PHP 5.5 and 7.0

Comment: what's the desired result on 2 character strings?

Comment: for it to be empty regardless of whether 1 or -1 comes first

Comment: I mean I figured out how to get around it, but its a weird behavior

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to work as intended on anything at all? Given `$s = "abcdefg"`, `substr(substr($s, 1), -1)` is `"g"`, not `"bcdef"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happen with `substr(substr('ab', 1), -1)`:

- `substr('ab', 1)` return `b`, and `substr('b', -1)` return `b`. Why? As *[documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)*, if the second argument of `substr` is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string.

instead with `substr(substr('ab', -1), 1)`:

- `substr('ab', -1)` will return `b`, and `substr('b', 1)` return `false`, because, always as documented: *If string is less than start characters long, FALSE will be returned.*

No bug here.